# Why using a LocationManager singleton in Android Activity is bad?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, singleton

In this [talk (15:49)](https://youtu.be/FrteWKKVyzI?t=949) it's said sth which I do not understand. It's something like "when you use a LocationManager singleton in Activity it will cause memory leak".

Can you explain how that LocationManager singleton causes a leak?

Comment: It might be because one might forget to remove the *listener*. It is only an assumption

Answer (score 1):

The LocationManager will hold a reference to the Activity.
LocationManager instance will live until your app is destroyed holding that activity reference.
meanwhile the user could navigate out of that activity.
now your LocationManager is holding a reference to a activity that has finished it's cycle but could not be destroyed because it is referenced from the LocationManager -> activity has been leaked.